# how to change block ordering in layouts

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, magento-2.0

I am creating a custom theme for Magento 2.

I have a header block defined this way (in `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` file):

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper"/>
<move element="header.panel" destination="header-wrapper"/>
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-content">
</referenceContainer>
```

With above definition, the base header-wrapper is used, which is in `module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

As you see, block order is:

1. `logo`
2. `top.links`
3. `cataog.topnav`
4. `header.panel`

However, when rendering, this HTML is shown:

```
<div class="header-content">
    <ul class="header links"></ul>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="minicart-wrapper" data-block="minicart"></div>
    <div class="block block-search"></div>
    <div class="panel header"></div>
    <nav class="navigation" role="navigation"></nav>
</div>
```

**Ordering is different from defined in layout.** How can I change it?

Answer (score 14):

To position elements you also need to add `before=""` or `after=""` when you define or move a block. But please note the block you are referencing in `before` or `after` must share the same parent as the block you're modifying.

For example if you wanted to position the logo before everything you would use:

```
<move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper" before="-" />
```

As `-` tells Magento to position it before everything else, `after="-"` would position it last.

To position an element before or after another element to use the block name instead of `-`, for example to position top.links after the logo you would use:

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

More on this can be found on the [official dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_xml-instrux_before-after)

Comment: I want to move the review tab in product page but it's not working as expected. Could you please look into this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281376/how-to-move-review-section-in-product-page and help me?