# Magento 2 Block/Element order

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, layout-update

A pretty basic question mainly because I'm still trying to wrap my head around Magento 2's templating system.  But I'm just trying to switch the order of the mini-cart element and the search element in the header so that the search element is before the mini-cart element in the markup.  For example, instead of

```
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">...</div>
<div class="block block-search">...</div>
```

I want it to be:

```
<div class="block block-search">...</div>
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">...</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101960/how-to-change-block-ordering-in-layouts

Comment: Or this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101960/how-to-change-block-ordering-in-layouts

Comment: @Roshni, I don't know why the same link. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question has asked many times but no one have explained briefly so I have decided to answer what is the essential part to make move elements.

whenever you want move position of the element, first you need to find that particular element resides on which layout file?

**For find appropriate layout file:**

for example I could take search form and mini cart

[image]

Enable debug mode in Admin in order to find the template path, please follow the below instruction to enable **template path hints**. first login to admin then follow

```
Store -> configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug -> Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront -> YES
```

after that flush the cache then load your page.you can able to see the template paths.

[image]

`/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml` use this template path you can find the layout location `/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

In that layout file you notice that  **form.mini.phtml** resides on block name **top.search** under **header-wrapper** container. similarly you can find the all appropriate layout file

`/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml` resides on block name "minicart" under **header-wrapper** container

**Move Elements:**

below line is do the trick of move elements. you can add this line in your **custom theme** layout.

```
<move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.search" />
```

Your layout file should be like below

`<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/<vendor-name>/<theme-name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart" />
    </body>
</page>
```

after that clear cache of magento and browser then load your page it look like

[image]

for any clarification you need, feel free to mention in comment.

have good luck.