# magento block won't move to container

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I'm trying to move blocks to different containers. I cannot seem to get them to move to the specified destination.

so in my default xml under Magento_Theme

```
<move element="report.bugs" destination="header.inner"/>

<referenceContainer name="abs.top.menu">
<container name="header.inner" label="Header Inner Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-inner">

</container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: This link will guide you how to move element http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117958/magento-2-block-element-order/117989#117989

Comment: Ok thank you, for the great reference links very resourceful.