# move minicart to after catalog.topnav magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

pls help me move minicart to after catalog.nav,im rewrite topmenu.phtml and call

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')->toHtml()

minicart show correct but when click popup minicart show content blank
```

Comment: refer this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117989/36463

Comment: i have try above code but its not working for me please help me move minicart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why you don't try to **move** it with xml update. Add this to default.xml layout in your theme:

```
<move element="minicart" destination="navigation.sections" />
```

The **navigation.sections** block is defined in **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**.

Then you need to override sections.phtml in your theme **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml** and display minicart block by adding this at the end of the file.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart') ?>
```

Comment: If I want to add in it header.phtml file. I've tried this code:

`<move element="minicart" destination="header.container" />` in default.xml and `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart'); ?>` in header.phtml but it does not work