# Load Block after another block but generate before

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, collection, product-collection

So I have a really interesting question.

I have a block that depends on `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

Basically I need to load this block after the collection is generated.

I'm using `getLoadedProductCollection` method to load the collection.

In my layout this block is in the header, so when I call this method in header, I expect the collection to load, but instead it returns an empty  collection.

When I call it after the `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` is loaded, then I get the expected collection.

But then this block is at the end of the page.

I could move this block by using jQuery, but I'm trying to avoid such a workaround.

What's is the best way to generate this block in header and have the collection loaded in `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

Thanks!

Comment: don't be complicated, I think you are not placed your block inside the correct reference block /container, could you show your layout file?

Comment: @BilalUsean That's the thing. If I place my block after `<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">` it works fine, but I need to load it in header.

Comment: after load, you can use `<move ../>` to move your block inside whatever container/block, easy for your reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117989/36463

Comment: @BilalUsean it doesn't work like that. I wish I could load the element first and than move it. The issue is that when you move element, magento loads blocks in final order of xml files, which includes if there were any changes to layout with move element.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind right now is, have you tried setting your module to load after `Magento_Catalog`?

```
//app/code/vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried it too. Seems like it doesn't work in terms of blocks, because even if I have sequence in place, it still doesn't load the collection