# Change Position of Custom tab of product page

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom tab on Magento 2 product page. The custom tab appears at the left side but I want it after detail and review tabs like **Details - | - Reviews - | - Custom Tab**

**Catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="tab.tab" template="Deno_Mymodule::extra_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Extra Tab</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Try something like this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101960/how-to-change-block-ordering-in-layouts

Key here is find names of block you want to move and destination block, and then add proper line in layout xml, which will move the block.

Do you want to make it for custom theme of your store?

Comment: I have edit the question, please check it. Thanks!

Comment: first of all - change your xml name for `catalog_product_view.xml` (lowercased)

Comment: @SyedMuneebUlHasan
have you moved your custom tab?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would consider changing class of your custom block, because you use some existing- block's class - so if you would like to add some more methods to you block class you will have to **override** magento native class, what is **not recommended**.

In case, that your tab should be something completely new I would make it with another class inheriting maybe, after `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`.

Now something about placing your tab - take a look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml:46` - you have a line:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
```

which has name of block, you want your custom one to be after (attribute **`name`**). Copy that name and add to your xml it like:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="tab.tab" template="Deno_Mymodule::extra_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" after=""product.info.review">.
```

Although I don't have full code of yours, so I can't test it, please try it and write about results in comment.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: please update question with full code

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://magenticians.com/add-custom-tab-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

**Well, I have changed the position of tabs by the details.phtml file:** (app/design/frontend/Nameplace/Themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml )

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')): ?>
    <?php $newOrderTabbing = array('product.info.description', 'product.attributes', 'reviews.tab', 'tab.tab'); //custom tab position   ?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($newOrderTabbing as $name): ?>
                <?php
                $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                if (!trim($html)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>-title">
                           <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use sort_order argument in

> "app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml"

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="tab.tab" 
    template="Deno_Mymodule::extra_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Extra Tab</argument>  
    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">30</argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```