# Magento 2: Add after/before positioning in pre existing xml block/container

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, cart, shopping-cart

I want to position few blocks and containers in the checkout page. I am using a custom theme and create a checkout_cart_index.xml file.The file contents are

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary" htmlClass="cart-summary clearafter">   
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cartbutton" template="Magento_Theme::cartbutton.phtml"/>    
            <move element="checkout.cart.shipping" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.summary.title" remove="true"/>


    </body>
</page>
```

But its not working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<move element="checkout.cart.shipping" destination="cart.summary" before="-"/>
```

This link helps me.

[how to change block ordering in layouts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101960/how-to-change-block-ordering-in-layouts)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **move** tags to move blocks.
`<move>` instruction: allows changing element's order and parent.

```
<move element="logo" destination="login.header" before="-"/>
```

**element:** name of the current block/container.

**destination:** name of the destination block/container where you moving element.

**before:** name of the block before which you need to move your block.

**after:** name of the block after which you need to move your block.

Refer this for more information:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html